# GZIP compression for css and js in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, compression, gzip

I have been through this link:
[CSS/JS GZip Compression with Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668774/css-js-gzip-compression-with-asp-net)

But this is not helping me.
I even wrote the settings in web config but what about css?
How do I compress that?
My code in web config:

```
<httpCompression 
  directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>

  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </dynamicTypes>

  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
```

Comment: Why do you know/assume that your CSS is _not_ transmitted compressed?

Comment: I have been detecting with YSLOW and it shows me that I need to compress css.

Comment: @ItiTyagi the firewall can also cause the unzipping of your files.

Comment: @Shekar: I am not getting this. I only need to know if I need to add some additional code for CSS compression? As I already compressed javscript and aspx pages

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution for the same.

There is also a setting in the IIS for enabling the static and dynamic compression.
Install the dynamic compression in IIS, and this will work.

Also I cleared the cache and re deployed the application and it worked.